# Are questions about maven appropriate on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, site-recommendation, scope

I have a question regarding the deployment of archetypes to an internal repository. Is this type of question appropriate to ask on Stack Overflow, or should it be asked on another Stack Exchange site such as Super User?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sounds fine for Stack Overflow.  Maven falls under [software tools commonly used by programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and there are 15K questions tagged [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) already.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of questions about [maven](/questions/tagged/maven), and a dozen of questions about [maven-deploy-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-deploy-plugin), so SO is a very good place to ask such questions, it has a large expert base, and your questions are quite likely to be answered there.